# Ocaml lwt symbols

Tags: ocaml

Any suggestions about the meaning of this symbol in Ocaml Lwt:

```
>>=
```

Answer (score 8):

See api [manual](http://ocsigen.org/lwt/api/Lwt):

> val bind : 'a t -> ('a -> 'b t) -> 'b t
>
> bind t f is a thread which first waits for the thread t to terminate
>   and then, if the thread succeeds, behaves as the application of
>   function f to the return value of t. If the thread t fails, bind t f
>   also fails, with the same exception.
>
> t >>= f is an alternative notation for bind t f.